# What would the equivalent machine learning program in R language of this Python one?

Tags: scikit-learn

As part of a school assignment on DSL and code generation, I have to translate the following program written in Python/Scikit-learn into R language (the topic of the exercise is an hypothetic Machine Learning DSL).

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_validate
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_error
df = pd.read_csv('boston.csv', sep=',')
df.head()
y = df["medv"]
X = df.drop(columns=["medv"])
clf = DecisionTreeRegressor()
scoring = ['neg_mean_absolute_error','neg_mean_squared_error']
results = cross_validate(clf, X, y, cv=6,scoring=scoring)
print('mean_absolute_errors = '+str(results['test_neg_mean_absolute_error']))
print('mean_squared_errors = '+str(results['test_neg_mean_squared_error']))
```

Since I'm a perfect newbie in Machine Learning, and especially in R, I can't do it.

Could someone help me ?

Comment: we are happy to assist you but not in homework. Learning anything new have a simple formula `TRY` -> `FAIL` -> `LEARN` -> `MAKE CORRECT`. Right now first understand what actually this code is doing and then search equivalent code.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late answer, probably you have already finished your school assignment. Of course we cannot just do it for you, you probably have to figure it out by yourself. Moreover, I don't get exactly what you need to do. But some tips are:

1. Read a csv file

data <-read.csv(file="name_of_the_file", header=TRUE, sep=",")
data <-as.data.frame(data)

The header=TRUE indicates that the file has one row which includes the names of the columns, the sep=',' is the same as in python (the seperator in the file is ',')
The as.data.frame makes sure that your data is kept in a dataframe format.

2. Add/delete a column

data<- data[,-"name_of_the_column_to_be_deleted"] #delete a column
data$name_of_column_to_be_added<- c(1:10) #add column

In order to add a column you will need to add the elements it will include. Also the # symbol indicates the beginning of a comment.

3. Modelling

For the modelling part I am not sure about what you want to achieve, but R offers a huge selection of algorithms to choose from (i.e. if you want to grow a tree take a look into the page https://www.statmethods.net/advstats/cart.html where it uses the following script to grow a tree

fit <- rpart(Kyphosis ~ Age + Number + Start,
   method="class", data=kyphosis))